# How to send list (primitive type or any class type) in SOAP request body

Tags: java, web-services, web, soap

I found problem when sending list in SOAP request.

```
<env:Envelope
xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<env:Header/>
<env:Body>
    <ns3:retrieveIndividualsBOBStatus
        xmlns=""
        xmlns:ns3="http://webservice.com/">
        <individualRequest>
            <Long>710039</Long>
        </individualRequest>
    </ns3:retrieveIndividualsBOBStatus>
</env:Body>
```

This is request body class. It contains list of Long type.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
 @XmlType(name = "retrieveIndividualsBOBStatus", propOrder = {
   "individualRequest"
 })
 public class RetrieveIndividualsBOBStatus {

    @XmlElement(type = Long.class)
    protected List<Long> individualRequest;

  /**
   * Gets the value of the individualRequest property.
    * ...
```

It always return null pointer exception because web service cannot read list elements. How to send list in SOAP request body?

Thank you for reading.